# Change the speed of USB ports

Tags: usb, speed, port

I'm working with a custom made board that isn't USB 2.0 compliant.

I was suggested by the manufacturer of the board to change my USB ports to "low speed mode" as I see frequent disconnects with the devices connected to the board.

I've poked around in device manager and in the bios and I can't seem to find the setting.

Can anyone please point me to it?

Thanks,

Parth

Comment: This would be done in the bios, if the bios supports it that is.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but have you considered checking around (ebay, etc) for a USB 1.0 or 1.1 PCI card?

Comment: It's for a corporate PC and IT is very strict on adding components to PCs managed by them.

Comment: If you need it to work to do your job they'll probably help you out. :)  What operating system are you using (name and edition please)?  What make/model of computer is it?

Comment: Windows XP Pro SP3. HP Compaq DC7900

Comment: How exactly do you know the board isn't USB 2.0 compatable?  My suggestion is to get the board manufacturer to make it compliant.

Comment: I spoke with them and they said it isnt. They're in the process of making a USB 2.0 compliant board, but it isn't priority for them